# Send Email when Task Assigned or Finished in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

Is there a way to send an email to the person who where assigned a task in a project or to send an email to the project manager when the task is finished ?

I'm working on OpenERP v6.1.

Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in two ways.

**Workflows**

The "vanilla" way is to use workflows: workflow Activities can trigger a Server Action that sends an e-mail when they are reached. You would need to create a workflow for your object (e.g. `project.task`). Remember to modify the view's state buttons from `type='object'`to `type='workflow'`. You can find an example [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp-commiter/openerp-mgmtsystem/trunk/view/head:/mgmtsystem_action/workflow_mgmtsystem_action.xml?start_revid=6).

This can be rather complicated if you're not familiar with module development in OpenERP. And IMHO it's a lot of trouble for such an "obvious" feature.

**Automated Actions**

That leads us to the second way to do it: using the `base_action_rule` module. Unfortunately it turns out that you're rather limited to what you can achieve with the module. So I wrote an extension, [`base_action_rule_trigger`](http://apps.openerp.com/addon/7738) to simplify the sort of 
automation you are trying to achieve.

For example, create a notification when a Project Issue is closed::

- In the Settings module, select menu Customization » Automated Actions, and create a new.
- In the "Conditions" tab: set the "Rule name" and "Object" fields.
- Set "Evaluated expression" to `changed.get('state') == 'done'`:

[image: Set "Evaluated expression"]

- In the "Actions" tab: set the "E-mail template" and check the "Send immediately" flag:

[image: set the "E-mail template"]

- The new "E-mail template" module is used to design and render the e-mail:

[image]

Other triggers expressions examples:

- Responsible is changed from user X to user Y: `old.get('user_id') and new.get('user_id') and old.get('user_id') != new.get('user_id')`
- A new or unassigned Issue : `inserting or changed.get('state') == 'draft' or not new.get('user_id')`

Answer (score 3):

You can override button object method,

```
    obj_mail_msg = self.pool.get('mail.message')
    obj_mail_server = self.pool.get('ir.mail_server')
    mail_server_ids = obj_mail_server.search(cr, uid, [], context=context)
    mail_server_record = obj_mail_server.browse(cr, uid, mail_server_ids)[0]
    obj_mail_msg.schedule_with_attach(cr, uid, 
                            email_from, 
                            email_to = [list of email], 
                            subject='Notification for Task',
                            body=tools.ustr(mail_body) or '', 
                            mail_server_id = mail_server_ids[0])
```

**schedule_with_attach** will create a massage in `(settings > configuration > Email > Massages)` and massage will be send by scheduler.

Hope it will Help.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply but where can I override button object method?

Answer (score 3):

Solution is to use 'email_template' module. install this module and you can find the configuration at `Settings > Configuration > Email > Outgoing Mail Servers` . Here you have the setup the outgoing mail server. Then goto `Settings > Configuration > Email > Templates` add the email template here for the model you want.

Now inherit your model and in the function (your button object to which change the task state to finish) add search for the corresponding email template and then use the `send_mail()` in the email_template module to send the mail.

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the answer. I did what you said but it doesn't send automatically the mail message to notify the assignee/manager. What it did was create a sidebar for action and when i clicked it, it opens a window to send the selected task. Then I will go to **Settings > Email > Messages** cause I found out that it will not send until you click send..

Did I miss something? Thanks

Comment: check whether you have created the template correctly.. please in the template form, in the advanced page add outgoing mail server. also check whether you have given the correct parameters for the sent_mail(), one parameter is template id and other is record id..

Answer (score 0):

you can use "email_template" module to send mail. First you need to create a template for that.
If you don't want to create email.template then you can directly use "send mail method" of "mail.message".

```
def send_email(cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    mail_server_obj = self.pool.get('ir.mail_server')
    mail_server_ids = mail_server_obj.search(cr, uid, [], context=context)
    if mail_server_ids:
        mail_message_obj = self.pool.get('mail.message')
        email_from = mail_server_obj.browse(cr, uid, mail_server_ids[0], context=context).smtp_user
        values = {
                'subject': your_subject,
                'body_html': your_body_message,
                'email_from': email_from,
                'email_to': email_to,
                'model': model_name,
                'res_id': ids[0],
                'mail_server_id': mail_server_ids and mail_server_ids[0],
                'date': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                'state': 'outgoing',
                'subtype': 'html',
            }
            msg_id = mail_message_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
            if msg_id:
                mail_message_obj.send(cr, uid, [msg_id], context=context)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is what I've used in one of my projects.
Perhaps filling in the mail server (smtp) parameters with yours would solve your problem.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(acc, pass);
    }
});
MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

Transport.send(mimeMessage);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply although I can send emails from OpenERP but when I assigned task, it doesn't send any emails to the employee.. I tried sever actions but it seems that i must configure more..